# how to access an item id to write a command for a button in a list view Xamarin

Tags: database, listview, xamarin, button, command

[how the app should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK8vi.png)
So I have a task to make two list views , the first one is connected to a local db ,the first one has  multiple cells each shows the properties of an item as well as an (add) button to add the item in a list that is used by the other list view , whenever you click (add) this item should be stored in that list and displayed by the second list view.

my question is how can I write a command for (add) button to do that?

Comment: You could use MVVM and define all binding in it. Then you could access the id of cell directly in command . In addition , it would be better to provide the relevant code so that people can help you better .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a ICommand (CommandToExecute) in your MVVM

ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvwView">
```

In listview datatemplate

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid x:Name="Item">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ImageButton Grid.Column="0" Source="{extensions:PlatformImage  SourceImage='Image'}" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference lvwView}, Path=BindingContext}" Command="{Binding CommandToExecute}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Then in your MVVM code, you only need handle object receive as parameter.